# remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Written code to get the notification on android device.
In this added the device id and registration id and application id of that android application but i run this page getting this error....
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

```
 private void AndroidPush()
    {
        string regId = "[the regid]";

        // applicationID means google Api key                                                                                                     
        var applicationID = "[the key]";
        //ProjectID (from API Console- google code)                                        
        var SENDER_ID = "[the id]";
        var value = Text1.Text; //message text box  
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        tRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        tRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

        tRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
                  + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;



        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();



        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();   //Get response from GCM server.  

        Label3.Text = sResponseFromServer;      //Assigning GCM response to Label text 
        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
    }
```

Comment: you need to pass some username and password, :/ that would work..

Comment: possible duplicate of [The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264672/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized)

Comment: Added Code for network credentials too but still getting the same error.

Comment: Added Credentials but still getting same error.          tRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UID", "PWD");

Comment: I'm not sure you need a username/password with a Google API key. I haven't tried it as I use OAUTH2. Have you enabled GCM in the Developers Console? What line is this failing on?

Comment: On this line showing an error                               WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to remote server if you don't enter Username and Password
[Check This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22845565/1882535) might be helpful.

Comment: Added Credentials but still getting same error.                                                              tRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UID", "PWD");